# To push a value of a int into a string without reassigning the original string value

Tags: java, rsa

So i have a value that is being returned from a class as an integer and this done several times according to the length of the text entered. I can print out the output for each character but i would like to combine the output into one string. This is an example of the output.

> Enter plain-text: hi
>
> The vaule of H is 7
>
> The encrypted value is 721 The decrypted value is 7
>
> The vaule of I is 8
>
> The encrypted value is 330 The decrypted value is 8

I would like it to print out the final cipher text as  `"721330"`, so that it would send it to a database and compare that value with the value store at the database.

What would be the best way to do this?

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int p = 29;
    int q = 41;
    int d = 83;
    int n = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int e=27;
    int c =1;
    String plainText;
    String Str = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

    //System.out.println(m);
    n = p*q;
    //System.out.println("The n value equals " + n);
    w = (p-1)*(q-1);
    //System.out.println("The w value equals " + w);

    int qo=0;
    int re=0;

    w = w*1+d*0;
    d = w*0+d*1;


    qo = w/d;
    //System.out.println("quotient value " + qo);
    re = w-qo*d;
    //System.out.println("reminder value " + re);
    qo=d/re;
    //System.out.println("quotient value " + qo);
    re = d-qo*re;
    //System.out.println("reminder value " + re);
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter plain-text:");
    plainText=scn.nextLine();

    plainText=plainText.toUpperCase();
    char[] chars = plainText.toCharArray();

    for (int i=0;i<chars.length;i++)
    { 

    int m= Str.indexOf(chars[i]);

    System.out.println("The value of " +chars[i] + " is " + m +"\n");

    toBin(e);
    //System.out.println("The binary value of e " + toBin(e));
    de_encryption(c,n,m,toBin(e));
    int C = de_encryption(c,n,m,toBin(e));

    //String final_output = String.valueOf(C);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    int part = C;
    sb.append(part);

    String result = sb.toString();
    //I want the final_output value to be appended into a stringbuilder
    System.out.println("The encrypted value is " + result);

    toBin(d);
    //System.out.println("The binary value of d " + toBin(d));

    int D = de_encryption(c,n,C,toBin(d));
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(); 
    int part1 = D;
    sb1.append(part1);

    String result1 = sb1.toString();
    System.out.println("The decrypted value is "+ result1 +"\n");


    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap a String with another String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking us how to create a String from multiple parts, by concatenating the parts.

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (...) { 
    String part = ...;
    sb.append(part);
} 
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I tried implementing this method but am not sure what to put into the "for" statement. I've added the code, hopefully it can help in answering the question. The final_output string is the string i want to append.

Comment: You already have your for loop: `for (int i=0;i<chars.length;i++)`

Comment: It appends the first value into the SB but when it run through the loop again and appends the 2 value it rewrites the whole string instead of inserting it to the end of the string. I'll update the code above to the new code. The output is the same.

Comment: @samibravo: re-read my answer. Of course the StringBuilder must be created **outside** of the loop, not inside as you're doing. Otherwise, you recreate a new StringBuilder, and forget about the previous one, at each iteration.